# Java BPEL Composite Application: not a valid xml schema element available in this wsdl file

Tags: java, xml, soap, soa, bpel

When I deploy my BPEL Composite Application, I get the error:

> ERROR: In part "parameters", attribute element's value "tns:hello" is
>   not a valid xml schema element available in this wsdl file. : Specify
>   a valid schema element value for element attribute.

Here is the CASA xml file where this error is happening:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             targetNamespace="RetailerBPELCA"
             xmlns:tns="RetailerBPELCA" xmlns:ns="http://retailer.sc.team7/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <import namespace="http://retailer.sc.team7/" location="../jbiServiceUnits/RetailerBPEL/localhost_8080/Retailer/RetailerService.wsdl"/>
    <portType name="dummyCasaPortType"/>
    <binding name="casaBinding1" type="ns:RetailerService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="hello">
            <soap:operation/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="processOrder">
            <soap:operation/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="orderConfirmation">
            <soap:operation/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="RetailerBPELCAService1">
        <port name="casaPort1" binding="tns:casaBinding1">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:${HttpDefaultPort}/RetailerBPELCAService1/casaPort1"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

And the original WSDL file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.1.1 (branches/2.1-6844; 2011-07-29T12:07:24+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5 JAXWS/2.2. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.1.1 (branches/2.1-6844; 2011-07-29T12:07:24+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5 JAXWS/2.2. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://retailer.sc.team7/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://retailer.sc.team7/" name="RetailerService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://retailer.sc.team7/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/Retailer/RetailerService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="hello">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/>
</message>
<message name="helloResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="processOrder">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:processOrder"/>
</message>
<message name="processOrderResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:processOrderResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="orderConfirmation">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:orderConfirmation"/>
</message>
<message name="orderConfirmationResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:orderConfirmationResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="RetailerService">
<operation name="hello">
<input wsam:Action="http://retailer.sc.team7/RetailerService/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://retailer.sc.team7/RetailerService/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="processOrder">
<input wsam:Action="http://retailer.sc.team7/RetailerService/processOrderRequest" message="tns:processOrder"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://retailer.sc.team7/RetailerService/processOrderResponse" message="tns:processOrderResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="orderConfirmation">
<input wsam:Action="http://retailer.sc.team7/RetailerService/orderConfirmationRequest" message="tns:orderConfirmation"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://retailer.sc.team7/RetailerService/orderConfirmationResponse" message="tns:orderConfirmationResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="RetailerServicePortBinding" type="tns:RetailerService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="hello">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="processOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="orderConfirmation">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="RetailerService">
<port name="RetailerServicePort" binding="tns:RetailerServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Retailer/RetailerService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

At deployment the WSDL gets parsed and the system must be able to access the referenced XSD schema in order to read the types. The way it is described now, the XML schema is on your localhost. Your server must be up and listening on port 8080 and nothing should be blocking the system from accessing the address.

Make sure the xsd schema is available for access at :

http://localhost:8080/Retailer/RetailerService?xsd=1.

If it available but it still doesn't deploy, you can try copying all the types referenced from the schema directly into the WSDL in the  section in the place of the  section.